# Directo copy batch file command

Tags: batch-file

How can copy a folder(located in the location of batch file)containing another folders and files to another location using batch file...
i am trying using command below but not working..

```
xcopy /E /Y %~p\DagwoodLoki@hp.com\* C:\Loki
```

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what "%~p" does but i think that following should work

xcopy %~p\DagwoodLoki@hp.com\ C:\Loki /E /Y

the /E and /Y must be written later the source and the target.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
xcopy /E /Y "%~dp0\DagwoodLoki@hp.com\*" C:\Loki
```

`%~dp0` is substituted with drive+path to the batch file, without quotes, if any.